# What is the best way to deal with EDT/non-EDT issues with JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, event-dispatch-thread

I have the following test method:

```
@Test public void f3KeystrokeShowsHotkeysDialog() throws AWTException{
    App app = new App();

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_F3 );

    try {
        Thread.sleep( 1000L );
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assertTrue( app.mainFrame.hotkeysDlg.isVisible() );
}
```

With the `sleep` this `assertTrue` passes; without it it fails.

The reason is obvious: `Robot`, which has to be executed in a non-EDT thread, and is here, generates a `KeyEvent` which the EDT takes a finite time to respond to.

The corresponding `Action` is as follows:

```
    ActionMap am = mainFrame.getRootPane().getActionMap();
    Action f3Action = new AbstractAction(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("# blip...");

            mainFrame.hotkeysDlg.setVisible( true );
        }
    };
    am.put( "show hotkeys", f3Action );
```

... `actionPerformed` is of course executed in the EDT.

Can someone who knows a lot about testing tell me:

1. should I do it like this, with an "arbitrary" sleep involved?
2. is there a better framework or technique for handling this, which I
       presume is a fairly common situation?
3. should I be avoiding this sort of testing altogether?  NB I am aware this is not "unit testing" as such, but it is (I think) functional testing: "press F3: a hotkeys dialog comes up" <-- this is a specification of the app...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this and interested in this sort of stuff just thought I'd distill what I think I've learnt over the past few days.

Firstly, it appears that testing of GUI functionality is something the "pros" add on at the end: first you get the guts of the app working...

Secondly, it appears that GUI testing is quite challenging.

Thirdly, I would replace the above code by this:

```
    App app = new App();
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F3);
    robot.waitForIdle();
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            assertTrue(app.mainFrame.hotkeysDlg.isVisible());
        }
    });
```

... demonstrating the use of `Robot.waitForIdle()` ... and also correctly (I believe) putting a test of visibility in the thread where it belongs, i.e. the EDT.  Anyway, it seems to work, which is good enough to be getting on with!

NB `EventQueue.invokeAndWait` is the less familiar sibling of `EventQueue.invokeLater`, but in a testing context like this it actually seems to be kind of crucial: if you use `invokeLater` there seems a high probability that the test will end, and clean up will happen, etc., before the `assertTrue` actually runs...